# Extended real numbers as algebraic structure

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, real-numbers

I need to work with real numbers, but extended to have an additional element. This element, I denote by $\odot$ and my set is: $\mathbb{R}_{\odot}=\mathbb{R}\cup\{\odot\}$. This element should behave as special "tagged" zero. For example $1+\odot=1$. That said I would like to treat this set as much as possible as  standard real numbers. For example it would be great to treat it as a ring and be able to re-use all ring-related theory. Are there any know ways of construcing algebraic structures like this? Any other suggestions of how to best represent something like this?

P.S. Sorry if my explanation is too informal. This is outside of my field so I am asking for help here.

Comment: What is $0 + \odot$?

Comment: For that matter, what is $1-1$?  It is very easy to show that in this case, it must be true that $0=\odot$.

Comment: $0+\odot=\odot$ and $1-1=0$. Another way to think about $\odot$ as "undefined" value which defaults to $0$.

Comment: Another idea I was thinking about is to "tag" all values, not just zero, although I am really interested in 0. In this case: $ \mathbb{R}_{\odot}=\mathbb{R}\times\{\odot\}$

Comment: The latter won't give you anything different than $\mathbb{R}$, it's isomorphic assuming operations defined pointwise. The zero element has to be $(0, \odot)$. Your "$\odot$ as undefined" notion seems blurry: why $ 0 + \odot = \odot$ but $1 + \odot = 1$? It's the latter that's surprising. Usually "NaN" (not-a-number) is like NULL values in databases -- expressions involving it generally collapse to that special value.

Comment: @BrianO thanks for the comment. I was to quick to write. What I mean by product type idea is more like: $\mathbb{R}_{\odot}=\mathbb{R}\times\{T,F\}$. It is like tuple of real and boolean. Does this structure makes more sense? Could it be a ring?

Comment: That's what I thought you were aiming for. Product, or, what comes to the same thing with finitely many constituent parts, direct sum: $\mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$, really the same as $ \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Z}_2$. Here, $\mathbb{Z}_2 = \mathbb{Z}/2$ is the integers mod 2, *the* 2-element ring (field, even). Yes this structure (the direct sum, I mean, $\cong$ the product) is a ring too (same underlying set for both, ordered pairs) However, I'm at a loss to think of an element of this structure that could naturally be thought of as meaning "undefined".